# Ubuntu Touch Emulator on 16.10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, 16.10, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

What sort of dire sorcery is required to make the Ubuntu Touch emulator work? I enabled Hardware Visualization in my BIOS, followed various tutorials, reinstalled everything a couple of times and still, i only see a black screen.

There are two Errors i can spot:

```
/sbin/adbd: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to maually install various versions of libgio using apt-get, but that didn't help.

```
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0 on /tmpmnt failed: Invalid argument
```

I suppose these errors are related, but I'm not sure.

Here's the full log: http://pastebin.com/AQtsyQ2j

I heard that the emulator is really slow, but how slow exactly? I let it sit for 30 minutes and nothing happened, that can't be right...

Comment: end of log: `/sbin/adbd: error while loading shared libraries: libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. this is the problem I think.

Comment: Just bought a used Nexus 4 as a debug device for 65 bucks on ebay so i can continue my testing. But still, I'd really like an answer to this question! I have this issue on two machines, one of them with a fairly plain installation of 16.10. No success. I'm really confused.

Comment: I suggest waiting for the smart Ubuntu devs to figure it out for us.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but a review of the pastebin log leads me to believe things start going wrong at line 356  "mmcblk0: unknown partition table" and I think everything else could be related to the inability to mount that file system thats on /dev/mmcblk0. I cannot seem to find anything definitive that indicates what file systems Ubuntu touch supports although based on the output you might try ext2 or ext3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Yakkety: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phablet-tools/+bug/1625182

The Ubuntu SDK IDE and the associated tools like the Emulator are currently unsupported, but some users report it still works in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus.

A good alternative to the emulator is using [clickable](http://clickable.bhdouglass.com/en/latest/index.html) to build the application in a docker container. With `clickable --desktop`, the app can be run on the desktop as well. This works on all versions of Ubuntu, as well as all other operating systems that support docker.