# pyotherside cannot be loaded on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, python, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I recently updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 and want to recover an old Ubuntu Touch App that I wrote using `pyotherside`. I have installed both packages

```
qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside
```

and

```
pyotherside
```

However, when I try to run my app from the Ubuntu SDK I get:

```
Main.qml:4 module "io.thp.pyotherside" is not installed
```

And when I try to import the `pyotherside` module within a Python3 shell, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pyotherside'
```

Does anyone have an idea what I forgot to do?

Sven

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is extremely broken in 16.10.

Issues include

- Wrong packages are chosen by the updater (this is probably what you're experiencing): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-ide/+bug/1647057
- Emulator does not boot: [Ubuntu Touch Emulator on 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854602/ubuntu-touch-emulator-on-16-10)
- Graphical UI designer does not work
- Random Crashes and instability

Given the development pace of the sdk up until now, i don't think it it will be fixed for 16.10 before the release of 17.04. I know this might not be a satisfying answer, but i recommend you downgrade to 16.04. It will save you a lot of hassle if you want to work with Ubuntu Touch.